# Function approximation(Parabola) using ANN in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to use a multi-layered perceptron to approximate a simple parabola. I've seen the code used for fitnet() but it doesn't make sense to me.

From what I understand, I give the MLP a limited number of inputs that describe the function  and it should figure out the rest of the points.

But how do I train and plot the before and after.

**EDIT**: This is what I was looking for:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCo2c2NJLSk&list=WLNHDPIzWjvUezymNTss-7lw

Code:

```
clc, clear all
% Data for a continous function
%[x, t] = simplefit_dataset;
x = -10:10;
t = x.^2;

net = fitnet(); 

%[net, tr] = train(NETWORK, NETWORK INPUTS, NETWORK TARGETS)
% [net, tr] net: new network. tr: training record
net = train(net, x, t);
view(net)
y = net(x);

%Plots
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};
perf = perform(net,y,t)
```

Comment: It is not clear, what is the problem. Can you give some details about that?

Comment: How can I give the NN sample points of the function( not all the points)  and let the multi-layered perceptron figure out the rest(regression/curve fitting?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
clc, clear all
% Generate data and visualize via plot
x = -10:.1:10;
t = x.^2;
plot(x,t);
% Define a NN object, net, and initialize it
% net = newff(min_max_values, [size1 size2 ... sizeNlayer], {activation_func_types, ...}, training_algo );
% Using trainlm = Levenberg-Marquardt optimization (choose any)
net = newff([-10 10], [10, 1], {'tansig', 'purelin'}, 'trainlm'); 
% Train the network (find the best network parameters to fit the data) and store it as net1
net1 = train(net, x, t);
% Simulate the result and the error
a = sim(net1, x);
% Plot the result and the error
plot(x,a-t,x,t,x,a);
```

Hope it helps.